# In Android, how to make an image randomly appear ??

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make three images randomly appear on screen at certain position in android. 
And I want to make those images clickable. If you click on a single image which is appeared the counter will be increased by one.
How do I go about it??

Comment: Where are you stuck? Do you know how to load the images? Do you draw on a Canvas? Do you know how to listen to touch events?

Comment: Could ya explain me draw on a Canvas and how can I use that in my problem. and "listen to touch events" is it same as setOnClickListener ??

Comment: So your question could be broken down into serveral little questions: how to get a random number (position)? how to show an image on the screen? how to respond to the clcik event on an image? Now, where do you get stuck?

Comment: I know how to show an image on the screen. But i need help with "how to make it appear and disappear randomly" and secondly how to make it clickable??

Comment: Are you using imageview to showing images?

Comment: Can I make a button appear and disappear randomly??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw an image on a Canvas using following code.

```
Rect dst = new Rect(x, y, x + imageWidth,y + imageHeight);

//enter paint as the last arg to use bitmap filtering
canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, null, dst, bitmapFilterSettings);
```

myBitmap is a [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html), bitmapFilterSettings is a [Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html). Place this code in your `onDraw()` method.

In order to place the image randomly, you have to randomize the `x` and `y` you pass to the `dst Rect`. In order to select a random image, you can put you Bitmaps in a `List` or an array and use the `nextInt(listSize)` method of [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html). In order to make the image appear and disappear randomly, use the `nextBoolean()` method of `Random` and only draw the image if it returns `true`. Do not do this too often (once every X frames), or your image will flicker.

EDIT : To do this you can declare a counter in the `Activity` and the number of frames between the decisions. You will also need a `boolean` field to switch drawing on and off.  In your `onDraw()` it could look like this:

```
counter++;
if(counter%framesBetweenDecision == 0){
 drawImageFlag = random.nextBoolean();
}
if(drawImageFlag){
//drawImage
}
```

To make the times between the decisions less predictable you could also randomize the `timeBetweenDecision`.

/EDIT

You can handle the touch event in your listener, calling the random image selection on each click. If you want to make only the image part clickable, check the location of your [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) (you can use the getX() and getY() methods) to lie inside the same [Rect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html) you are using to draw you image using it's `contains(x, y)` method.

This is not the only way to achieve this, but a quite straightforward one.

Comment: "Do not do this too often (once every X frames), or your image will flicker."
How should I  implement this.